# matlab code on geometric random variable

Tags: matlab

I am asked to Write a code to generate a geometric RV with p=0.25 and use it to calculate the probability that the RV takes a value greater than or equal to 4. Basically, I am not aware of matlab but I tried using help in matlab. And I came to know that I should use geornd function. Can anyone help me how to use the function and how I should enter the parameters to get the required results?

Answer (score 2):

See the doc for this function: http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/geornd.html.

For example, if you want a 1x10000 vector of geometric samples with parameter p=0.25, use

```
values = geornd(.25,1,10000);
```

To estimate the probability that the RV exceeds or equals 4:

```
mean(values>=4)
```

Explanation: `values>=4` is a vector which contains 1 or 0 according to whether the condition is fulfilled or not. Its sample mean (function `mean`) is an *estimation* of the probability of that event.

Anyway, in this case it would be easier to compute that probability *exactly*:

```
>> p = .25; N = 4; 1 - p*sum((1-p).^[0:N-1])

ans =

    0.3164
```

or using `geocdf`:

```
p = .25; N = 4; 1-geocdf(N-1,p)
```